# Global Event handler for Touch Up Inside

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a touch operation that is a trigger for resize kind of scenario, where the operation starts on touches move, and needs to end on touchesEnded. The thing is, that the touchesEnd could be on a different UI View, since the user is dragging the finger. How do I register a *global" touchesEnded listener?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Each time it triggers, check the `state` of the gesture recognizer. If it's `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` then the view is first being touched, if it's `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` then the user is moving his finger, if it's `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` then the user has lifted his finger.

As long as the gesture starts on your view it will continue (unless cancelled) even after leaves the bounds of the view, so you don't need to worry about "making it global".

Initialize the gesture recogniser with:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *dragViewGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDragView:)];
dragViewGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:dragViewGestureRecognizer];
```

Then fill out the following method with the code you need:

```
- (void)handleDragView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGestureRecognizer {
    switch (panGestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            //Code when dragging starts
            break;
        } case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            //Code while dragging is happening (if needed)
            break;
        } case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            //Code when dragging ends
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is great!! how do I get the UIView that the finger is currently on?

Comment: The event will only trigger if the initial touch is "captured" by the view that you add the gesture handler to (`yourView` in the code above). If you have multiple gesture controllers on multiple views accessing the same method, you can get the view that triggered the event by accessing `panGestureRecognizer.view` from within the `handleDragView:` method.